# How to check plugin status in telegraf?

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-plugins

This is self added Q & A. I am using telegraf's `Telegraf 1.14.0` version, I have configured a few `input.exec` for plugins in my `telegraf.conf` file, now wanted to check if my configuration is working fine with all configured plugins(eg-->status on console). Is there a command for making sure all configured plugins status by command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check working and status of all plugins configured in telegraf we could use following command. Written and tested in `Telegraf 1.14.0` version.

```
telegraf -test -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

Where:

- `telegraf.conf` is the main configuration file where all plugins are mentioned for gathering monitoring details. Make sure run this with user by which telegraf software is installed.